# pinescript to draw horizontal lines with for loop

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Below pinescript code gives me an error,

```
Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='open_grid'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected.

Cannot use 'hline' in local scope.
```

Basically I would like to draw horizontal lines by for loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Example 1", overlay = true)


float open_init = 20000
float tp = 100


for var i = 0 to 2
    float open_grid = open_init + (tp) * i

    hline( open_grid, "open",  color.lime)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw horizontal lines from the `for` loop, use the `line.new()` function instead of `hline()`. The script below also uses the `barstate.islast` condition to prevent lines from being drawn on every bar of the chart.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Example 1", overlay = true)

float open_init = 20000
float tp = 100

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to 2
        float open_grid = open_init + (tp) * i
        line.new(bar_index, open_grid, bar_index + 1, open_grid, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.lime)
```